# How to connect to ibus-daemon

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, system, ibus, preferences

In my terminal on Kubuntu 16.04 I frequently see the following:

```
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: No such file or directory                                                                               
QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /home/iris/.config/ibus/bus                                                                                                                                                                               
Bus::open: Can not get ibus-daemon's address.                                                                                                                                                                                                      
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon
```

It happens, for example, when I open a pdf with okular but it seems to happen in many instances, also when I've left my computer unattended for a while. I have not found anything that can help me get rid of these messages, maybe also because I don't know why I get these messages so I don't know very well what to search for. I've found [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37362-no-connection-to-ibus-daemon-inotify_add_watch-failed) which suggests I start IBus in 'system -> preferences', but I have no clue where to find it in Kubuntu 16.04. I can only find 'system settings' which does not seem to be what I need.

I would like to know what this message means and how to prevent it from showing (I assume it indicates something is not working properly)

Comment: That would make the question longer, but maybe that is better. I'll edit the question and add this information.

Comment: this is a much better question; unfortunately I do not have the answer. however, check that the path mention exists

Comment: Thanks, and indeed the path doesn't exist. There is no ibus in /home/iris/.config/

Comment: I see exactly the same message when I open a pdf using okular from the terminal. Until now, I usually launch pdfs by clicking on them in Dolphin. Launching applications from the terminal is usual when trying to troubleshoot something. It isn't the preferred route. In short, don't worry unless something isn't working with the application, in this case okular.

Comment: Incidentally, this terminal message doesn't show up in Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I get this (on Suse Linux) when trying to install an HP MFP M181fw using `hplip`. I get Bus::open: Connect ibus failed! 
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon 
The printer works via USB but not via LAN or WLAN: printing a test page fails in those cases. I do not know what "System Preferences" corresponds to in Suse. `ibus restart` (which I tried) is meant to restart the daemon, I see no open files containing `ibus`, but I do see two `ibus-daemon` processes, one with `-xim -d` and one with `-xim -panel disable`.

Comment: I think this may be an irrelevant message: I fixed my problem (open `slp` and `mdns` in the firewall) and still see this although my printer now seems to work fine.